# Javascript - Modify a function or evaluate a function from string

Tags: javascript, function, eval

This is what I currently have:

```
test(function(){
    console.dir('testing');
});

// Input a function

function test(fn){
    console.dir(fn.toString().replace('dir','log'));
    // console: function (){console.log('testing');}

    // try to evaluate string back to a function
    eval(fn.toString().replace('dir','log'));
}
```

Can I modify something in a function (eg,'testing' to 'hello world')

or evaluate modified string of function back to a function?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
test(function(){
    console.dir('testing');
    alert('done');
});

// Input a function

function test(fn){
    console.dir(fn.toString().replace('dir','log'));
    // console: function (){console.log('testing');}

    // try to evaluate string back to a function
    var f;
    eval('f = ' + fn.toString().replace('dir','log'));
    f();
```

}

Comment: Oh man, this is so simple and can't imagine that I didn't have thought of that. Thanks!

Comment: More expclicit would be `var f = new Function(...code...);`. I don't think it's a good idea to use a regular expression to parse script, or any programming code.

Comment: -1 This would break code which contained part of a property name with `dir` in it, e.g. `obj.direction` would be changed to `obj.logection`. Also, this does not work if there is more than one call to `console.dir`, as `String.prototype.replace` only replaces the first instance found if passed a string as the first argument.

Answer (score 0):

Following code produces the same result :

```
function test(action, fn) {
    fn(action);
}
test('log', function (action) {
    console[action]('testing');
});
```